# Avoid Laravel facade on controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 5.5` and trying to get used to code by [psr-2 standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) (just started learning). I analyze all my code with [Quafoo QA](https://github.com/Qafoo/QualityAnalyzer) and go step by step fixing the errors and record them.

By using facades i get this error `"Avoid using static access to class"`. Because of it i'm trying to avoid using them.
**On my controller i have this code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Events\FileLoaded;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\StringHelper;
use \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;

class LoadDataController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $viewfactory = app(ViewFactory::class);
        return $viewfactory->make('LoadData/index');
    }

    //more code
}
```

Besides the `View Facade` i also use `DB, Input, Validator and Storage`
Is this the correct way, are there others?

Comment: A [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades) in `Laravel` provides static interface to methods but those are not really static. So I think you should read about facades in `Laravel`. Using a `Facade` is not bad in the context of `Laravel` (IMO), it's a featured offered by the framework and it'll not hurt.

Comment: Yeah, this is essentially a false positive.

Comment: Indeed `Facades` are good in `Laravel` but as i said i'm trying to learn the standard so i needed a workaround that work's everywhere and not just in `Laravel`.
Still thanks for the comments and clarifiactions.
@ceejayoz in `Laravel` it should be a false positive :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to avoid `Facades` - they are a key part of the framework.  But if you want to, you can use dependency injection to include the classes you need as arguments in the controller methods:

```
class LoadDataController extends Controller
{

  public function index(ViewFactory $viewFactory)
  {
    return $viewfactory->make('LoadData/index');
  }

  //more code
}
```

Or if you need that in all the controller methods:

```
class LoadDataController extends Controller
{
  private $viewFactory;

  public function __construct(ViewFactory $viewFactory)
  {
    $this->viewFactory = $viewFactory;
  }

  public function index()
  {
    return $this->viewFactory->make('LoadData/index');
  }

  //more code
}
```

Of course, this doesn't actually change the functionality of the code you've written, it just rearranges it.  I wouldn't take the word of the code analyzer you mentioned as something you are doing wrong.  These are standard patterns to use in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:  
I know about `Facades` and the fact that in `Laravel` are not a bad thing.
But as i'm trying to learn the standar i want to abstract myself from the framework. Though is kinda of ilogic if i'm using it ^^!